# Scraping <li> usingg puppeter/ cheerio

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I've tried using a loop with a selector to scrape the `<li>`, but it doesn't work.

i want to get "Program Studi Perencanaan Wilayah Dan Kota"
this value and the other value

Node Cheerio code:

```js
$('div#panel-penggiat-collapse-0 > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > span > span > span > ul > li').each((i, el) => {
  console.log($(el).text())
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Perencanaan Wilayah Dan Kota"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Perencanaan Wilayah Dan Kota</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Matematika"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Matematika</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Fisika"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Fisika</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Statistika"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Statistika</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Sistem Informasi"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Sistem Informasi</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Desain Komunikasi Visual"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Desain Komunikasi Visual</li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Program Studi Teknik Komputer"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Program Studi Teknik Komputer</li>
  <li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A big chunk of the HTML context here is missing so naturally this selector won't work on this HTML as shown. Please add details so others can help. What doesn't work exactly? What's the site? Why are you using Cheerio and Puppeteer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have issues with your selector. There is nothing wrong in your code.

I have put your code here:

https://scrapeninja.net/cheerio-sandbox?slug=8669ef61805c9903e3845656681d8d02de44aabc

and console.log works properly for simpler selector.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. When you reach 50 rep you can comment.

Comment: can u help to get the "Program Studi Statistika" and the others

Comment: I am not sure I understand your request correctly.. but take a look at this: https://scrapeninja.net/cheerio-sandbox?slug=daca4fe381cae72003c44a7fbbea5b52e136afbd

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess but possibly:

```
$('ul.select2-selection__rendered li').first().text()
```